# What will happen if two different size generators are paralleled?

Tags: generator

What will happen if I Parallel two different size generators of different manufacturers without a synchronizing panel. Both generators have the same voltage and frequency.

Comment: *without a synchronizing panel* the fuses would blow, because the phase is not 0

Comment: Two synchronous generators? If they are not in phase when you close the switch, you'll put them both in short-circuit condition.

Answer (score 1):

As AlexVS said, the two generators will short-circuit. This might damage the generator of less power.

When the generators are in synchronicity, all power is delivered to the consumer (resistor R on the picture). The resistor is consuming maximum generated power of  2.2W.

[image: Synchonisity]

If one generator is out of synchronisity, one part of generated power will remain circulating between two generators, depending how much the generator is out of synchonisity. This might damage the smaller generator, increases the heat of both generators and consumer is not getting all the available power. On the picture below, the generator U2 is 40° out of synchonisity.

[image: 40° out of synchronisity]

Source: falstad.com

Answer (score 1):

Different sizes, different manufacturers have nothing to do with it.

To operate two synchronous generators in parallel, phase sequence, frequency,  voltage and phase difference must be identical.

Phase sequence is rotation in same direction.

Frequency is the rate of rotation.  Both must rotate at 50Hz, 60Hz or any frequency, say 55Hz on a ship.  This is governed by the motors the generators must supply.  Supply 50Hz to 60Hz motors or vice versa and motor operation would not be at rated conditions.

Finally, voltage may vary, but must be close.  Larger voltage generator will force lower voltage generator to increae it's voltage so they are identical.

Generators are connected in parallel via a synchroscope and 3 synchronizing lights.  The lights are connected between oncoming generator and online generator.  When both generators are in phase, lights are off.  Out of phase by 180° and lights are brighest.  The brigher the lights, the larger the phase difference between generators and the larger the adjustment current.

From GeoGebra [Synchroscope (and Syncronizing Lights)](https://www.geogebra.org/m/dQfgGtF5) to illustrate the problem.  You want Δa (a - a') (Δb, Δc) to be as small as possible, as in 0, to minimize inpact as the oncoming generator is brought online.  In picture, phase difference ϕ is 152°.  Lights are bright and synchroscope is at 7 o'clock position.  Look at the instantaneous waveforms.  When Red is at a max, Dashed Red is almost at a negative max.  Think about it like two powered mechanical gears coming together.  If the teeth do not mesh correctly, they will break off.  Same thing for generators.  The electrical teeth are to different to mesh smoothly.

[image: GeoGebra's Synchroscope]

In reality, to parallel two generators, you actually want the oncoming generator to be spinning a little faster, say 60.05Hz.  This is to allow oncoming generator to take up the load.

But as the breaker is connected for the oncoming generator, the powered generator drives the oncoming generator so that the frequency (phase difference) is the same.  The bigger the phase difference between the oncoming and online generator, the larger the adjustment.  This adjustment is via current.  Synchronous generators are synchronous machines.  They can function as a generator or motor.  So the oncoming generator motors for an instant.

Two random generators connected together will trip breakers because of this adjustment current and possibly cause permanent damage to generators, breakers, panels and wiring.